# Conditional expectation of multiple random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We were given the following question. If N is the number of customers entering a store, and $X_{i}$ is the amount of money the $i^{th}$ customer spends and each of the $X_{i}s$ are identically distributed independent random variables, what is the expected value of T, the total amount of money spent? I am not really sure how to approach this question, except conditioning on the fact that $E[T]= E[\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}]$. I know there are 2 random variables here, but where to go on from there?

Comment: Looks like a repeat of another post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is assumed here that $N$ is independent of th $X_i$'s. Conditioning on $N$ we have $E[T]=\sum P(N=n)E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i]=\sum P(N=n)(nE[X_i])=E[X_1] \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} nP(N=n) =E[X_1]E[N]$ since $E[X_i]=E[X_1]$ for all $i$.

Comment: How do you get $ET=\sum P(N=n)E\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i$?

Comment: When you condition on $N$ it acts like a constant. So $E \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} X_i $ is just $N$ times $EX_1$ (since expecattion is linear) . Now multiply by the probability that $N=n$ and sum over $n$. @user1234

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is a given number,

For linearity of expectation

$$E[X_1+X_2+ \dots +X_n]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_n]=nE[X_1]$$

If $N$ is a rv, first assume independence between $N$ and $X_i$'s then condition the expectation using

$$E(\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}X_i)=E[E(\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}X_i|N)]=E[N E(X_1)]=nE(X_1)$$

Where I set $n=E(N)$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is an infinite sequence of customers, but we only see the first $N$ of them. Thus, we can think of $X_i$ as defined for all $i$.

Let $I\{i \le N\} = 1$ if $i \le N$ and $0$ otherwise.

The expected money from the first $N$ of them is
$$
E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^N X_i \right] = E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty I\{i \le N\} X_i \right]
$$

Since the expectation is linear, we can write this as:
$$
E\left[ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty I\{i \le N\} X_i \right] =
\sum_{i = 1}^\infty E[ I\{i \le N\} X_i ]
$$

If the $N$ and the $X_i$ are independent, then we have $E[ I\{i \le N\} X_i ] = E[I\{i \le N\}]E[X_i]$. Then:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^\infty E[ I\{i \le N\} X_i ] =
\sum_{i = 1}^\infty E[I\{i \le N\}]E[X_i] =
E[X_i]\sum_{i = 1}^\infty E[I\{i \le N\}] =
E[X_i] E[N]
$$